# How to make score increase score on touch?

Tags: android, mobile, lua, coronasdk

I'm working on a simple ball-type game for Corona SDK, and I currently want the game's score to increase by one whenever a ball on screen is touched. Currently whenever it happens the text variable for score disappears and nothing else happens. How do I make the score increase?
Here's my code:

---

```
function touchBall(event)
local ball = event.target
local score = 0;
scoreNum.text = score
scoreNum:setReferencePoint(display.CenterLeftReferencePoint);
score = score + 1
ball_h = 5

ball:applyLinearImpulse(0, -0.2, event.x, event.y)
ball_h = ball.y
if ball_h > 50 then
    gameover();
end
if event.target == "touch" then
    score = score + 1
    scoreNum.text = score
end

end

ball:addEventListener("touch", touchBall)
ball2:addEventListener("touch", touchBall)
ball3:addEventListener("touch", touchBall)



end
```

Comment: In your code line 3, "local score = 0;" local means the variable "score" only use for this function, but the function "touchBall(event)" will be called many times, when called this function the variable "score" will be set 0, so you should put the "local score = 0;" out of the function "touchBall(event)" .

Answer (score 1):

Create a Runtime Listener to maintain the score changes.

```
        local function runtimeListener( event )
           scoreNum.text=score
        end
        Runtime:addEventListener("enterFrame",runtimeListener)
```

Remove the line 15 and insert it as given above.

This makes the score keep on changing according to the touches..